# Running a sound with javax.sound.sampled.Clip in the background

Tags: java, audio

So I am trying to create a game intro with music starting out at a certain point when changing the picture with the code below. The audio plays, but pauses the intro until the track finishes, and then the intro resumes. Is there any way to keep the track playing in the background?
Thanks

```
public void launcherbackgroundsound(File lbgs)
{
    try
    {
        Clip mm_clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        mm_clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(lbgs));
        mm_clip.start();
        Thread.sleep(mm_clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
    }
    catch (Exception lbgs_err1)
    {
        System.out.println("Music track not found! No audio to play in game! ");
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to run the clip in its own thread rather than in the **Event Dispatch Thread** (EDT).

Comment: How would one do that

Answer (score 0):

Lose the `Thread.sleep` command.

That is all you have to do. The `Clip` will be played in its own thread automatically. Clips are given their own "daemon" status threads when played. As long as your program is running a daemon thread will continue to execute. Daemon threads are used with Clips and SourceDataLines so that an unfinished sound will not prevent a program from ending when all normal threads have finished.

Also, you should load the `Clip` during startup, not just before starting it. Clips are designed to be preloaded and saved in memory, to be used on an as-needed basis. So, store the loaded clip as a class-level variable/instance variable. That is the common practice.